# Unique list of variable strings for model estimation

Tags: r

I want to create a vector of unique variable combinations to estimate various regression models for different sets of variables, while fixing one variable to be always included.
For example, I always want to include variable X1, plus a distinct combination of up to, say, three (this threshold could be varying depending on the specific data and research question at hand) other variables from the full list of available variables X2, X3, ..., XN.
The bi-variate case is rather simple, I guess.
However, already for tri-variate models, the variable combination "X1 X2 X3" will yield the same coefficients as "X1 X3 X2". Further, I also want to exclude combinations which contain same variables twice, e.g "X1 X2 X2".

How to exclude these "double-counting"/redundant combinations best? Or how to create such a vector of all possible distinct combinations?

**Test code i tried so far (separating variables with underscore):**

```
library(dplyr)
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

A <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5") # all variables in dataset
a <- "X1" # keep X1 in all models
A_minus_a <- A[A %!in% a]

# first combination:
C1 <- outer(a,  A_minus_a, paste, sep = "_")

# second set of combinations:
C2 <- outer(C1,  A_minus_a, paste, sep = "_") %>% as.vector

# third set of combinations:
C3 <- outer(C2,  A_minus_a, paste, sep = "_") %>% as.vector

# full list of model combinations, but including many "double-counted"/redundant models:    
C <- c(C1, C2, C3)
```

Any help you can provide is very much appreciated!

*P.S. for the second step I could prevent the problem by formatting the result of outer() into a matrix and then extracting the lower triangular elements without the diagonal of the matrix. However, when turning to the third set of combinations this does not work anymore. So, there might be a better solution from start.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `combn()`? e.g. for sets of three variables:

```
cc <- combn(A_minus_a, m=3)
apply(cc,2,paste,collapse="_")
## [1] "X2_X3_X4" "X2_X3_X5" "X2_X4_X5" "X3_X4_X5"
```